# Elasticsearch 7 - Sort on custom field of multi-field property

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am working on upgrading a system at work from using ES1 to ES7.

Part of the ES1 implementation included a custom plugin to add an analyzer for custom sorting. The custom sorting behavior we have is similar to "natural sort", but extended to deal with legal codes. For example, it will sort `1.1.1` before `1.10.1`. We've been calling this "legal sort". We used this plugin to add an extra `.legalsort` field to multi-field properties in our index, and then we would sort based on this field when searching.

I am currently trying to adapt the main logic for indexing and searching to ES7. I am not trying to replace the "legal sort" plugin yet. When trying to implement sorting for searches, I ran into the error *Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default*. The solution I've seen suggested for that is to add a `.keyword` field for any text properties, which will be used for sorting and aggregation. This "works", but I don't see how I can then apply our old logic of sorting based on a `.legalsort` field.

Is there a way to sort on a field other than `.keyword`, which can use a custom analyzer, like we were able to in ES1?

Answer (score 1):

The important aspect is not the name of your field (like *.keyword), but the type of field. For exact match searches, sorting and aggregation the type of the field should be “keyword“.

If you only use the legalsort field for display, sorting, aggregations or exact match, simply change the type from “text” to “keyword”.

If you want to use the same information for both purposes, it’s recommended to make it a multi-field by itself. Use the “keyword”-type field for sorting, aggregations and exact match search and use the “text”-type field for full-text search.

Having 2 types available for the 2 purposes is a significant improvement over the single string type you had in ES 1.0. When you sorted in ES 1.0, the information stored in the inverted index, had to get uninverted and was kept in RAM. This datastructure was/has been called fielddata. It was unbounded and often caused out-of-memory exceptions. Newer versions of Lucene introduced an alternative data structure which resides on disk (and in the file system cache) as a “replacement” to the “fielddata” data structure. It’s named doc-values and allows to sort on huge amounts of data without consuming significant amount of heap RAM. The only drawback: docvalues are not available for analyzed text (fields of type text), hence the need for a field of type keyword.

You also could set the mapping parameter “fielddata” to true for your legalsort field, enabling fielddata for this particular field to get back the previous behaviour with all its drawbacks

Comment: Some of the fields we want to "legal sort" are used for full text search, filtering, and sorting. For example, we want to support matching with slop on the Name property, but we also want to legal-sort by that property.

Comment: Updated my answer above